# How to run vuejs project with django app together?

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, deployment

I am developing the front-end side in VueJs and backend-side in Django. I am using REST API for the connection between front-end and backend. After building the VueJS project, I received the dist folder. Is it right way to run this dist folder inside django project?
Is it good way to continue?

`path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name='index')`
The index.html is generated by after building VueJs project.

Comment: You don't run front-end (Vue) in your django project. Front and Back ends should be seperate apps. And connect with REST API endpoints.